# Condition if/else based on a multiple choice question on Bot Framework Composer

Tags: conditional-statements, bot-framework-composer

I create a multiple choice question on Bot Framework Composer and I want to create a condition based on the answer from the user.
The choices are clickable buttons and the answer is stored in  a variable.
There is a condition placed, but when the user click on YES, which supposed to go forward, the answer comes a NO.
I'm new on Bot Framework Composer and any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For buttons you can use attachments like hero cards or adaptive cards.
Please try this.[image]